# Error al ecualizar un histograma de una imagen en hsv

Tags: python, imagen

tenemos que hacer un ejercicio sobre tratamiento de imágenes. El caso que nos ocupa es hacer una ecualización de histograma; este es el código de python que tenemos:

```
imagen = cv2.imread('images/lsc23.jpg')
plt.title('Imagen original')
plt.show()
print("\n-->Cogemos la componente Value\n")

imagen_hsv=rgb_to_hsv(imagen)

componente_V=imagen_hsv[:,:,2]
plt.imshow(np.uint8(componente_V))
plt.show()


print("\n\n-->Histograma de las componentes V\n")

arrayV = componente_V.flatten()
plt.hist(arrayV, 256, range=[0, 255])
plt.show()
```

Hasta aquí está todo bien, pero a la hora de ecualizar en la siguiente sentencia nos salta un error y no llegamos a razonar el por qué

```
print("\n\n-->Igualación de Histogramas de la componente V\n")

equalized_V = cv2.equalizeHist(np.uint8(componente_V))
plt.imshow(equalized_V)
plt.show()
```

A ver si nos podéis aclarar un poco. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿cual es el mensaje de error completo?

Answer (score 0):

Miguel, ordené un poco el código, y frente al hecho de que no incluiste los **import** en él, los asumí; Creo que el problema estaba en que te faltaba o tenías mal escrita, la siguiente línea del código:

> from matplotlib.colors import rgb_to_hsv

Pues estabas llamando a **rgb_to_hsv** sin tenerlo declarado. El código que incluye lo anterior queda así:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import rgb_to_hsv


imagen = cv2.imread("aaaa.jpg")
plt.title('Imagen original')
plt.imshow(imagen)
plt.show()

imagen_hsv = rgb_to_hsv(imagen)
componente_V = imagen_hsv[:,:,2]
plt.title("Cogemos la componente Value")
plt.imshow(np.uint8(componente_V))
plt.show()

arrayV = componente_V.flatten()
plt.title("Histograma de las componentes")
plt.hist(arrayV, 256, range=[0, 255])
plt.show()
```

Espero que esto resuelva tus dudas, y en caso de que no sea así, que te sirva para complementar lo que tienes.